# Jquery select table rows and group them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has a list of employees. I want to be able to create a new department and drag and drop employees into each department. Once an employee has been assigned to a dept, the dept column in the "employeedept" table has to get updated with the dept value.

```
<table id="employeedept" border="1">
    <THEAD> <tr> <th> Dept</th> <th> Name</th> </tr> </THEAD>    
    <tr> <td></td>  <td> John </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td></td>  <td> Tom </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td></td>  <td> Smith </td> </tr>
</table>

<input style="margin-top:20px;" name="deptname" id="deptname"  />
<input type="button" id="dtnDept" value="Add New Dept" onclick="createDept()" />
```

Is there any JQuery plugin around that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking involves a couple different steps.

1. Ajax request to pull in existing employees and departments
2. User fiddles about
3. Ajax request posting in new distribution of employees
4. Server side script changes things in the database.

jQuery can help you with the ajax requests, and the part where the user fiddles about with the table.  There's a couple plugins like [this](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/), but I'd use the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) plugin with the sortable command.

Comment: #1 and #3 are taken care of, I need to focus on being able to create new departments and drag/drop employees into that dept. Once employees are assigned department, I store this information in Javascript variables, allow the user to do more stuff on the page, and finally on submit send all the information back to the server

Comment: Sounds good!  Is there anything besides the name of the plugins I can help you with?

Comment: The Table Drag and Drop plugin really doesn't suit my need. I'm looking for something so that I can create a new department and then drop employees into this department bucket.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting awfully specific for a jQuery plugin.  Try using jQuery UI to handle existing departments, and your own jQuery to create new departments.  A simple way to do this is to create a set of <div>'s for existing departments, have a button to create new <div>'s for new departments, and all users as <li>'s that you can move with the jQuery UI plugin into those <div>'s (this all comes naturally with the plugin).  After that you just need to serialize the output when you want to save and move onto step 3!